# Why does Memcached add() always succeed, regardless of expire time?

Tags: php, memcached

I'm adding a key using Memcached like so:

```
$valueToStore = time(); // some number
$success = $memcached->add( 'test_key', $valueToStore, 20 ); // cache for 20 seconds
```

But it's always succeeding when I call it in a different session, even before 20 seconds have passed. According to the docs at http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.add.php, it should be returning FALSE until the key expires (because the key already exists).

I'm running on a single development server with plenty of free cache space. Any idea what might be happening?

`php -v` returns: `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3`
memcached version 2.1.0
libmemcached version 1.0.8.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be distinct if you are using the `Memcache` class or the `Memcached` class. Your cache design is a bit strange. You should be checking the cache to first see if the item is there. If the item is not then store it. Also `Memcache` has some strange behavior on using the boolen type  as the third argument. You should `MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED`. I think you are using `Memcache`.

To illustrate how to fix your problem:

```
$in_cache = $memcached->get('test_key');
if($in_cache)
  return $in_cache;
else
  $valueToStore = time();
  $memcached->add('test_key', $valueToStore, MEMCACHE_COMPRESS, 20);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using `Memcached::add` because I want this operation to be atomic. After the key expires, I want only one script to successfully add the key and any others that try will fail until the next time the key expires.